Movie with two men who steal a car and kidnap a girl (child)
I can't for the life of me remember what this movie is called, and I thought I'd try this place.
I saw it when I was younger, so I believe it has to be an 80's or early 90's movie.
I thought it was Burt Reynolds and Dom Deluise, but from what I can see on IMDB that's incorrect.
As far as I can remember, they steal/drive one of those american cars where the trunk is double-doored. (Glass on top, door at the bottom)
I believe it to be an accidental kidnapping, but they take good care of her.
The more I try to think about it, the less details I can remember.

And you're sure it's not Cannonball Run? It's with both of them and I think Reynolds kidnaps Farrah Fawcett. Also, was she in the trunk?

No, it's definately not cannonball run. The kidnappee is a child.

Is it a zany comedy, like something Dom Deluise would be in, or is it a drama? The tone of the movie might help readers narrow it down.

Probably Savannah Smiles. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084633/ 
She runaway from her parents and hides in the car of two not too bright crooks who take very good care of her. The movie is on youtube 



YES! Thanks! ^_^
It wasn't DOm Deluise, but at least they are both big men :P
